# WordPress: overwrite function in parent theme from child themes function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-fonts

on my WordPress site the Google Fonts are loaded via a file in the parent theme and I want to disable loading them. I already tried using WP Plugins but they didnt work.

Currently I just go into the file and place a return statement into the function which loads the fonts. But the problem is that everytime the theme updates, I will have to rewrite the function again.

So now I am looking for a solution with which I can overwrite this function in this specific file from my child themes functions.php (if this is even possible).

I have already tried:

```
add_filter( 'load_fonts_google', '__return_false' );
```

```
remove_action( 'init', 'load_fonts_google' );
```

```
if ( function_exists( 'load_fonts_google' ) ) {
    /**
     * Dequeue Google Fonts.
     */
    function load_fonts_google($fonts) {
        return;
    }
}
```

```
function remove_my_parent_theme_function() {
    remove_action('after_setup_theme', 'load_fonts_google');
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'remove_my_parent_theme_function');
```

NOTE: load_fonts_google() is the function I want to remove/overwrite.

Comment: And what is the original function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the "OMGF" Plugin from WP